# Execution order of meteor-collection-hook and simple-schema validation is different on the server and the client

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection-hooks

I am using collection2, simple-schema and meteor-collection-hooks.

**First test**

```
// posts.js
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Posts.before.insert((userId, doc) => {
  console.log('Should see this');
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Works fine both in meteor shell and console:
Posts.insert({title: 'some title'});
```

**Second test**

```
// posts.js
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

Posts.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
  }
}));

Posts.before.insert((userId, doc) => {
  console.log('POSTS BEFORE INSERT');
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
  doc.slug = 'whatever';
});

Posts.allow({
  insert: function() {return true},
  update: function() {return true},
  remove: function() {return true}
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then in meteor shell:
Posts.insert({title: 'some title'}); // validation error. No console.log. No Post inserted.
//
// Error: Slug is required
//    at getErrorObject (packages/aldeed_collection2/packages/aldeed_collection2.js:425:1)
//    at [object Object].doValidate (packages/aldeed_collection2/packages/aldeed_collection2.js:408:1)
//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In the chrome console:
Posts.insert({title: 'some title'}); // works just fine. I have a post with a title, slug and created_at
```

In my second test in meteor shell, the validation is run **before** the hook, so the Post is invalid and the hook is **not executed at all** (it needs to first pass through the hook to be valid).

Interestingly, I have not this problem while on the client. On the client, the execution order seems valid: hook THEN validation.

Do you have the same behavior ?
Any idea why the order is different on the server?

---

A workaround is to do this on the server:

```
Posts.insert({title: 'some title'}, {validate: false});
```

But I loose the validation, which I would like to keep...

See [Github issue](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/issues/154)